# Modx - Extend site_content - Add new table

Tags: modx

Currently, we're running revolution 2.2. On site_content, we have some tags that are ran for crawling twitter. I want to start tracking the number of results for each tag as results come in, to determine which tags don't return that many results, etc.

So I was thinking that I should create a new table (twitter_data), and have a foreign key that will link it to the search tag ID, which is stored in site_content.

What is the best path to accomplish this? Should I create my table then run the reverse schema tool, outlined here?

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Reverse+Engineer+xPDO+Classes+from+Existing+Database+Table#ReverseEngineerxPDOClassesfromExistingDatabaseTable-CreatingaMySQLtable

I also found this, but not sure if this is what I should be looking into:

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Custom+Database+Tables+in+your+3rd+Party+Components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not - if you can avoid modifying the core modx schema do so. an external table may be your best option, but requires a fair bit of work. 
though if you can explain wht you mean by 'tags' a little better [html tags? snippets? content tags? not sure what you mean] there may be other options. for example. one of our clients wanted to count page hits [and didn't want to use google to do it] so all we did was to create a template variable bound to each page they wanted to count and then updated that appropriate variable by writing  plugin to fire on the onpageload or onpagerender event. [I don't ermember exactly which or what it was called]

Basically, you may be able to do this by writng a plugin rather than trying to extend anything or add snippets/chunks.

Comment: By tags I mean: In the modx_site_content I store tags for various clients. Example: "Xbox 360" would be a twitter search tag. Now, when the crawler runs, I want to store some data, like how many results, etc.